# Ansible: import_role doesn't expose variables to a playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-role

My ultimate goal is to load some hashes (or dictionaries) with variables used as constants. A dedicated role seems perfect for that purpose as it can be reused in many playbooks. The [Using Roles](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles) chapter in Ansible docs says:

> - If roles/x/vars/main.yml exists, variables listed therein will be added to the play.

which means the variables loaded by importing a role should be available in play scope for subsequent tasks/roles. All perfect.

But I can't get it work as expected (Ansible 2.4.2):

```
$ ansible-playbook $HOSTS test.yaml

PLAY [local] **************************************

TASK [constants : debug] **************************
ok: [local] => {
    "myvar": "myvar contents"
}

TASK [debug] **************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "myvar": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
...
$ cat test.yaml
- hosts: local

  tasks:

    - import_role:
        name: constants

    - debug: var=myvar

$ cat roles/constants/vars/main.yml
myvar: myvar contents

$ cat roles/constants/tasks/main.yml
- debug: var=myvar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I did add a task to a role just to check if the variable gets defined inside the role. For my scenario I don't want any tasks, just variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing is wrong, Ansible `import_role` and `include_role` currently work like this:

- [include_role does not expose variables to rest of playbook](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/21890)

---

Use the "legacy" roles declaration:

```
- hosts: local
  roles:
    - constants
  tasks:    
    - debug:
        var: myvar
```

Comment: Indeed. Didn't think about checking the "legacy" way. Thanks!